# What purpose can anonymous modules serve?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activesupport

What purpose could [anonymous modules](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#anonymous) in a Ruby app serve?  The concept itself is easy to grasp, but I can't imagine any reason that you'd ever use such a thing.  What problem do they solve?

Comment: This page lists an example use of anonymous modules - http://www.intridea.com/blog/2012/2/13/using-anonymous-classes-and-modules-in-ruby  It's a bit esoteric but it's a way to collect together a bunch of different methods, on the fly.

Comment: The simple answer is that they let you create short-lived namespaces for things, the mixin example in the link is the only usecase *I've* used them for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a more general principle at work here.

Phil Karlton famously said: ["There are only two hard problems computer science: cache invalidation and naming things."](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html) So, naming things is hard. Which means that if we can get away with *not* naming a thing, we should do it!

Or, if you look at it from a different perspective: if naming things is hard, then giving something a name means that thing is important. But sometimes, there are things in our programs which *aren't* important and thus aren't worthy of a name.

This is not unique to Ruby modules. You could ask the question about any anonymous concept, and in fact, the question *does* get asked all the time. When C# 2.0 introduced anonymous methods, people asked why one would ever want to use a method without a name, when C# 3.0 introduced anonymous lambdas (and anonymous types), people asked why one would ever want to use them. Python's anonymous functions are severely restricted compared to Python's named functions, and the Python community asks why one would ever need full-blown anonymous functions. Of course, we, as Ruby programmers are so used to lightweight (blocks) and fully reified (`Proc`s) anonymous functions that we can't understand why one would ever *not* want to use one.

Java has anonymous classes since 1.1 and anonymous lambdas since 8. Basically, anonymous "things" are everywhere and they are useful, especially for quick one-off usage.

For example, if you just want to wrap some existing method, without going through the hassle of `alias_method` (which you really shouldn't use any more for that problem, `Module#prepend` now exists and is a much better solution), you could do:

```
class Array
  prepend(Module.new do
    def [](*)
      puts 'Before-hook'
      super.tap { puts 'After-hook' }
    end
  end)
end

p [42][0]
# Before-hook
# After-hook
# => 42
```

Comment: brilliant and clear.  Now that you've pointed it out with a simple example, it seems like it should have been obvious.

Answer (score 5):

*This is a Rails specific answer, it's not about anonymous modules in general.*

#### Short answer

Being able to call `super` when overriding generated methods.

#### Long answer

Given a module that creates methods:

```
module Generator
  def generate_method(name)
    define_method(name) do
      "I am #{name}"
    end
  end
end
```

Calling `generate_method` from within a class creates a new instance method:

```
class MyClass
  extend Generator
  generate_method :foo
end

MyClass.new.method(:foo) #=> #<Method: MyClass#foo>
```

Invoking the method works as expected:

```
MyClass.new.foo #=> "I am foo"
```

But you can't easily alter `foo`:

```
class MyClass
  def foo
    super.upcase
  end
end

MyClass.new.foo #=> no superclass method `foo'
```

If our generator uses an anonymous module to define the methods within:

```
module Generator
  def generate_method(name)
    generated_methods.module_eval do
      define_method(name) do
        "I am #{name}"
      end
    end
  end

  def generated_methods
    @generated_methods ||= begin
      mod = Module.new
      include(mod)
      mod
    end
  end
end
```

We get:

```
class MyClass
  extend Generator
  generate_method :foo
end

MyClass.new.method(:foo) #=> #<Method: MyClass(#<Module:0x007fbd29833658>)#foo>
```

And altering `foo` now works as expected:

```
class MyClass
  def foo
    super.upcase
  end
end

MyClass.new.foo #=> "I AM FOO"
```

Comment: That seems like a pretty convoluted usecase--making a class pretend it's a subclass of something. What's the usecase for wanting to do that?

Comment: @DaveNewton Rails generates a lot of methods and you often have to alter the default implementations, e.g. overriding a getter or setter. Being able to call `super` makes it more convenient, I think.

Comment: @DaveNewton updated my answer to clarify that it is Rails specific (it was not obvious). The example is indeed convoluted, but so is Rails ;-)