# define_method multiple times with the same name

Tags: ruby

I've written a little wrapper over `method_missing` like this:

```
module Util
  def method_missing_for(regex, &blk1)
    define_method(:method_missing) do |name, *args, &blk2|
      match = name.to_s.scan(regex).flatten[0]
      if match
        blk1.call(match, *args, &blk2)
      else
        super(name, *args, &blk2)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then using it:

```
class Foo
  extend Util
  method_missing_for(/^say_(.+)$/){ |word| puts word }
end

Foo.new.say_hello
# => "hello"
```

The problem is that I cannot call this multiple times for a class. The `method_missing` I add with `define_method` just gets overridden. What alternative do I have? Conceptually I know I can refactor `method_missing_for` to take multiple regex => block mappings and then call it once instead of multiple times. At its core it would be a big case statement which tests all the regex. But I would rather be able to take advantage of `super`.

```
class Foo
  extend Util
  method_missing_for(/^say_(.+)$/) { |word| puts word }
  method_missing_for(/foobar/) {}
end
Foo.new.say_hello # => NoMethodError
```

Comment: Strategically you'll want to define a singular `method_missing` method that intercepts and dispatches through some kind of lookup table. `method_missing_for` should create that method if it doesn't exist, then append an entry to the mapping table.

Comment: thanks @tadman that makes sense, I was just posting this to see if there's some way around it I wasn't aware of.

Comment: That's how a lot of DSL-type meta-programming methods work. You need to have some kind of state you're manipulating in addition to your bridge method.

Comment: @tadman I've heard of the concept of adding method to an inheritance chain, so I was wondering if that could be a way

Comment: If I make an anonymous module could I append it to the ancestors list?

Comment: @maxple yes you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that I cannot call this multiple times for a class. The `method_missing` I add with `define_method` just gets overridden.

No, it doesn't. It gets over*written*.

You already have the solution in that sentence: you need to over*ride* it instead:

```
module Util
  def method_missing_for(regex, &blk1)
    prepend(Module.new do
    ##################### this is the only change compared to your code
      define_method(:method_missing) do |name, *args, &blk2|
        match = name.to_s.scan(regex).flatten[0]
        if match
          blk1.(match, *args, &blk2)
        else
          super(name, *args, &blk2)
        end
      end
    end)
    ####
  end
end

class Foo
  extend Util
  method_missing_for(/^say_(.+)$/) { |word| puts word }
  method_missing_for(/foobar/) {}
end
Foo.new.say_hello
# hello
```

Note: it may or may not be beneficial to name the module, so that it shows up with a sensible name in the ancestors chain, which improves the debugging experience:

```
Foo.ancestors
#=> [#<Module:0x007fa5fd800f98>, #<Module:0x007fa5fd801df8>, Foo, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

See also [*When monkey patching a method, can you call the overridden method from the new implementation?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4471202/2988) for a more comprehensive treatment.

Comment: Thanks, I was currently working on a solution from your answer to [what-purpose-can-anonymous-modules-serve](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075993/what-purpose-can-anonymous-modules-serve) which pretty much looks like this

Comment: Funny that I added in the paragraph about naming :-D

Answer (score 0):

My idea is to *register* the definition when declaring, and define those methods when all the declaration is done. The usage will be a little bit different, but I think is still acceptable

```
class Foo
  extend Util

  phantom_methods do
    method_missing_for(/^say_(.+)$/){ |word| puts word }
    method_missing_for(/^foo_(.+)$/){ |word| puts word }
  end
end
```

The implementation of `Util` will be

```
module Util
  def phantom_methods
    # Initialize the registration table
    @_phantom_methods = {}

    # Allow declaring methods
    yield

    # Consume the registration table and define a single `method_missing`
    define_method(:method_missing) do |name, *args, &blk|
      pair = self.class.instance_variable_get(:@_phantom_methods).find {|regexp, prc| name =~ regexp}
      pair ? pair[1].call($1) : super(name, *args, &blk)
    end

    # Good practice to also define `respond_to_missing?`
    define_method(:respond_to_missing?) do |name, include_private = false|
      self.class.instance_variable_get(:@_phantom_methods).any? {|regexp, _| name =~ regexp}
    end
  end

  # Declare a phantom method
  def method_missing_for(regexp, &blk)
    # Register the definition
    @_phantom_methods[regexp] = blk
  end
end
```

By the way, I borrowed the phrase *phantom method* from [this book](https://pragprog.com/book/ppmetr2/metaprogramming-ruby).